# Random sample after adding extra elements

Tags: probability, sampling

I have $N$ sensor measurements ($N=5000000$) and a random sample of size $s$ ($s=20$) from this set of data. For each measurement is computed a rank as being the minimum distance to the sample values. So finally we will have $5000000$ ranks.
The problem is how do we compute the ranks when $100$ new measurements are retrieved, so now we have $5000100$ data objects. We could generate a new random sample $s_1$ and repeat all computations for all $5000100$ measurements. I want to avoid this since it is computational expensive.
So I was thinking to keep the already generated sample s and already generated $5000000$ ranks and compute the rank incrementally only for the new $100$ observations.
Is any way to asses the error that would be introduced if we would compute the ranks for the $100$ new values referring to the old sample $s$?

Example

$N=10$ [$2$ $7$ $10$ $2$ $6$ $9$ $11$ $3$ $15$ $8$]
$s=3$ [$10$ $7$ $2$]

rank[$2$]$=0$
rank[$7$]$=0$
rank[$10$]$=0$
rank[$2$]$=0$
rank[$6$]$=1$
rank[$9$]$=1$
rank[$11$]$=1$
rank[$3$]$=1$
rank[$15$]$=5$
rank[$8$]$=1$

suppose we have $3$ new observations [$5$ $19$ $4$] the new set of observations would be

[$2$ $7$ $10$ $2$ $6$ $9$ $11$ $3$ $15$ $8$ $5$ $9$ $14$]

Is not correct to consider that for this set a random sample is [$10$ $7$ $2$] since we give no chance of being selected to the new introduced elements.
Still considering that the random sample is [$10$ $7$ $2$] how can we estimate the error of computing the ranks for [$5$ $19$ $4$] in respect to sample [$10$ $7$ $2$] , i.e
rank[$5$]$=2$
rank[$19$]$=9$
rank[$4$]$=2$

what would be the error of taking these values as real ranks?

Thanks and regards
Sorin

Answer (score 0):

let us see how often you end with the new measurements in the random sample:
$$p = 1- \frac{{N \choose s}}{{N+100 \choose s}}$$.

Using the known bounds such as $ \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^k <{n \choose k} < \left(\frac{e\cdot n}{k}\right)^k $, we can show that $p \to 0$ as long as $\frac{s}{N} \to 0$.

In your case s=20 and N=5000000, so I would assume that your initial calculations would remain true with a very high probability.

Comment: ok, thanks, i tried to calculate the probability that none of the new measurements are chosen in the random sample (so we can use with error=0 the old sample), and if i am not wrong, that is $$  p=(1-\frac{1}{N+n})^{n*s} $$ which for N=5000000, s=20 and n=100 evaluates to p=0.9996000879459642 which is quite certain. is any way to give bounds for the error of the ranks computed with respect to the old sample s?

Comment: The probability, $p$ is a lower bound on the accuracy of ranks computed from the old sample. We can say this because if some new measurement is included in the random sample, it may not necessarily change the ranks of other measurements. I do not see any simple way of improving this bound as it will depend on the values in the old sample and all your measurements.
consider the rank of measurement $i$ with old sample = $r_i$ and say one new measurement got added to the random sample. Two scenarios occur, either the closest element to this measurement is replaced or not.

Comment: if not, you can evaluate the probability that the old rank is still valid( P(distance to old point < distance to newly added point). If replaced, the rank changes (unless the new value is same as the replaced measurement). This way you can improve on the bound per element basis but it is tedious. Not to mention we have only considered one new value got added to the sample. You can iteratively improve on the bound. I would really like to know if there is a simpler way to improve on the lower bound.

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain how you computed the probability to end up with new measurements in the sample to be $$p = 1- \frac{{N \choose s}}{{N+100 \choose s}}$$ ? Also, is it correct my evaluation that the probability that none of the new measurements are chosen in the random sample is $$ p=(1-\frac{1}{N+n})^{n*s}$$. I evaluated first the probability of one new measurement to not be draw in the sample to be   $$p=(1-\frac{1}{N+n})^{s}$$ and then multiply n times that.

Comment: Number of ways to choose $s$ samples from $(N+n)$ measurements is $b = { N+n \choose s}$.  <br>
Number of ways to choose $s$ samples from only the $N$ old measurements is $a = { N \choose s}$.  <br>
Then $\frac{a}{b}$ is the probability that only the old measurements show up in the random sample.
I do not think your calculation is exact. Once a sample is picked the probability changes. Hence you cannot multiply it n times.

Comment: Ok, not sure which of my assumptions is wrong. Let's consider a new measurement, o1. The probability that o1 is not chosen in s is  $$p1=(1-\frac{1}{N+n})^{s}. (A)$$. Then take another new measurement o2. The probability p2 that o2 is not chosen in s is $$p2=(1-\frac{1}{N+n})^{s}. (B)$$. Then the probability that neither o1, nor o2 are chosen in s is $$p1*p2 (C)$$. Based on this, taking into account that there are n new measurements we have $$p1*p2*...pn (D)$$ multiplying n times, so finally we get $$ p=(1-\frac{1}{N+n})^{n*s} (E) $$. Which of these equations (A),(B)... to (E) are wrong?

Comment: Let us look at a simpler example to find out what is wrong. Let ${a,b,c,d}$ be four items. what is the probability that $a$ does not show up in a random sample of two items. 
All two item combinations: ${ab,ac, ad, bc, bd, cd}$. Hence the probability=1/2. (also equal to ${3 \choose 2}/{4 \choose 2}$).
Using your logic we get $\frac{3}{4}*\frac{3}{4}$, which isn't incorrect.
I realize the confusion is due to the lack of information on how we are generating the random sample. if it is with replacement, your calculation is correct. If it is without replacement then my calculation is correct.